# creating clickhouse Settings Profiles

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to use clickhouse setting profile,
I added to users.xml this profile:
<max_result_rows>3000</max_result_rows>
and I created user:
CREATE USER web IDENTIFIED WITH no_password  SETTINGS  PROFILE 'web'
and gave him select permission on a table I created
when I am running select I am getting 5000 rows and not 3000 limit why is that?
what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use limit as well in your query .

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity/#result-overflow-mode

Using ‘break’ is similar to using LIMIT. Break interrupts execution only at the block level. This means that amount of returned rows is greater than max_result_rows, multiple of max_block_size and depends on max_threads.